# Firewalls block ports, but ports like 80 are usually open, is that bad security?

Tags: security, networking, port, firewall

Really I'm confused on two counts:

1) what badness can happen if you have all your ports open (no firewall)
2) why that can't happen on ports like 80, 20, etc. which are usually open

If you have any suggestions on something to watch/read I'd be much obliged!

Comment: Youll find some great answers here http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45659/why-block-network-ports and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24310/why-block-outgoing-network-traffic-with-a-firewall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question needs two answer parts. Incoming connections and outgoing connections.

The main reason for blocking ports is to limit the attacks that can be executed against the system. With all ports open, malware can easily communicate with servers the attacker controls and a number of attacks become significantly easier.

When a server blocks all incoming connections except on port 80 and then runs a web server on port 80, an attacker with user-level access to the server can't create any listeners. He/she might be able to kill the web server and then listen on port 80, but this would require root privileges and be fairly easy to detect (as the web server goes down).

When a server blocks all outgoing connections except for those associated with an already established session, a similar goal is observed. It prevents applications (i.e. malware) on the server from sending data back to the attacker. The established rule exceptions are required as protocols such as HTTP are answered from high ports instead of port 80.

Comment: i spent some time yesterday reading about this yesterday, what you say definitely makes sense.  thank you :)